# How can I find the posterior distribution for gammadistributed data and prior?

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, posterior, gamma-distribution

I'm working on a project where I believe Bayesian statistics should be useful. However, my knowledge about bayesian statistics are very scarce. Suppose I got data following a Gammadistribution with a known shape-parameters of $\alpha = 11.26$ and the estimated parameters for the prior are, $a=1.08$ and $b=13.7$ (a being shape and b being rate).

For the prior I got a gammadistribution:
$$
f(\theta) = \frac{b^{a}}{Γ(a)} \theta^{a-1} exp(-b\theta)
$$

And the likelihood:
$$
L(x|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{Γ(\alpha)}\theta^{\alpha}exp(-\theta  x_i) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha n}}{Γ(\alpha)}\theta^{\alpha n}exp(-\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)
$$

Thus the posterior is:
$$
f(\theta|x) ∝ \theta^{a-1} exp(-b\theta) * \theta^{\alpha}exp(-\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i) = \theta^{a+\alpha n - 1}exp(-\theta(b + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)
$$

This will then be a $Ga(a+\alpha n, b + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)$ am I right?

However, when I plug in the values for $(a+\alpha n, b + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)$,  I get a distribution that is not possible/true. The posterior distribution will be $Ga(1250.94, 17.39)$,the plotted distribution moves very far away from both the data and prior, the distribution should be closer to the data rather than be further away? Is the posterior parameters not the distribution or have I missunderstod something?
Or is it possible that it's not at all a probability density function I'm plotting?

Comment: The likelihood is a function of the parameter given the data: $L(\theta|x)$. Is the likelihood gamma as well? Then you got the formula wrong. Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Conjugate_prior) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_i|\theta\sim\mathcal G(\alpha,\theta)$ for $1\le i\le n$, and $\theta$ is the [rate parameter of the Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), the likelihood is
$$L(\theta|\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha-1}\Gamma(\alpha)^{-n}\theta^{\alpha n}\exp\{-\theta n\bar x_n\}\propto \theta^{\alpha n}\exp\{-\theta n\bar x_n\}$$
and the associated posterior is indeed
$$\theta|\mathbf x \sim \mathcal G(a+\alpha n,b+n\bar x_n)$$
with mean
$$\mathbb E[\theta|\mathbf x]=\dfrac{a+\alpha n}{b+n\bar x_n}$$
It is difficult to understand what you mean by

> a distribution that is not possible/true

Comment: Oh just so I get this, the posterior parameters are the ”distribution” for my rate parameter and not a probability density function for the with knowledge of the prior and likelihood if you know what I mean..
That’s why my answer are ”false”/not possible. I’ve missunderstood my answer

Comment: Do you mean you've misunderstood your question OR my answer?!

Comment: Missunderstood my result I mean, sorry for my poor english… Thanks for your answer :)